# reference ospecialize and variable prim_base_irreducible not found in the current environment

Tags: coq

Error encountered when trying to make after  `coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile` for [lambda-rust](https://gitlab.mpi-sws.org/iris/lambda-rust/-/tree/master?ref_type=heads)

```
macs-MacBook-Pro:lambda-rust mac$ make
COQC theories/lifetime/model/creation.v
^Cmake[1]: *** [theories/lifetime/model/creation.vo] Interrupt: 2
make: *** [all] Interrupt: 2

macs-MacBook-Pro:lambda-rust mac$  make -j8
COQC theories/lifetime/model/accessors.v
COQC theories/lifetime/model/creation.v
COQC theories/lifetime/model/borrow.v
COQC theories/lang/lang.v
File "./theories/lifetime/model/creation.v", line 80, characters 2-13:
Error: The reference ospecialize was not found in the current environment.

make[1]: *** [theories/lifetime/model/creation.vo] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
File "./theories/lang/lang.v", line 627, characters 8-29:
Error: The variable prim_base_irreducible was not found in the current
environment.

make[1]: *** [theories/lang/lang.vo] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```